# Write iteration number into function in df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I would like to add values to a DataFrame column with df.apply(). The values are the index multiplied with 6.

```py
import pandas as pd

# make a simple dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], "b": [3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]})
print(df)


def func(i):
    return 6 * i


# create an unattached column with an index
df.apply(lambda row: row.a + row.b, axis=1)

df["d"] = df.apply(lambda i: func(i), axis=1)

print(df)
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Can someone help me our and explain why I receive this error. I know this is a very simple example and there are plenty of posts and tutorials on `pd.df.apply()` but somehow I can't get this work.

Comment: Something is wonky here. From what I can understand, `apply`  is the wrong tool. You want to add two columns together and multiply each row by 6?

Comment: `df['d'] = (df['a'] + df['b']) * 6`

Comment: what @roganjosh said : why not add them first without apply then use it if absolutely needed : `df['a'].add(df['b']).apply(func)` (*you dont need the axis=1*)but really you dont need to use apply for such vectorized usecases , also why you recieve the error is because you are applying the finction on 2 columns not on the added series

Comment: @anky_91 the function just multiplies the input by 6 :/

Comment: @roganjosh yes agreed you dont need apply for that , I edited my comment a little :)

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message.